# usb otg thermal printer interface to android tab with usb device

Tags: usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go, usb-peripherals, thermal-printer

I have printer with USB OTG capability which I want to use with my Android Tab (as USB device).

Is this possible -- and if so, will it work for all Android versions from 2.3 up? Is there any driver needed for this communication?

Comment: I don't know the device, but usually there's some driver required for the communication with printers. Have you checked the playstore? I never came across something concerning directly-attached printers, but there are several for CUPS or special printers around, not necessarily involving the cloud. If your printer supports PostScript, check out [this list](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=postscript+intitle%3Aprint&c=apps).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this App?  Supports Ethernet, USB or Serial (with serial-USB adapter). 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=qsrtech.posprintdriver

Also, try this app from Opera Mobile Store. If this app doesn't work with your printer, send printer profile to the app server. They might add support.
http://apps.opera.com/en_in/usb_printer_driver_21_developer_edition.html