# printing solution on android which prints to a dotmatrix POS printer through **USB**

Tags: settings, usb, usb-drivers, usb-on-the-go, printing

am newbie for android.

I was looking for a printing solution on android which prints to a dotmatrix POS printer through **USB**.

I'm able to print some non readable symbols from android tablet (through some third party apps like printhand,printershare). These apps don't have driver for this cheap printer(TVS-RP45-Shoppe).

I have a 'PPD' file of the Dotmatrix POS printer.

I need to know how to install this PPD file into android.

similar to this >> [usb otg thermal printer interface to android tab with usb device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42345/usb-otg-thermal-printer-interface-to-android-tab-with-usb-device) But I have the PPD file.

Andoid tablet MID ST-10 Karbonn smart tab - android ICS

printer TVS-RP45-Shoppe

Trying to print programmatically like usb interfacing. any help highly appreciated .

Thank you all.

Comment: Just a suggestion, printing over a network is a lot easier, especially if it is a cheap printer and you are having USB driver issues. If you can print over a network you should try that as an alternative if you can't get it to work over USB.

Comment: Thankyou john,But the user who about to use this would not have any network fecility, and they dont want bluetooth solution also which was printing something atleast.

Comment: More over am very much interested in finding the usb solution since a newbie.

Can you tell me will it work if I gain root access and install the PPD file for the printer?
OR
Can you suggest me a way to write a code which reads PPD file from SD card and prints through usb?.

Which is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

My advice: Root your device first. Then copy that available PPD file into particular APPS driver location and proceed USB printing.